# Screen reader consistency issue

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda, jaws-screen-reader

I am using Jaws 15 and IE 8 to test acccessibility of my website and found some weird issue with role alert on page load if I am having any role alert which is apart of DOM on page load JAWS/NVDA never announce alert.

In some case role alert is not getting announced by JAWS/NVDA when I do show hide of role alert parent container i.e.:

```
<div clas="container">
  <div role="alert" tabindex=-1 class="validation-summary">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=# >Please enter first name</a></li>
      <li> <a href=# >Please enter lastname</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

To get it announced I put focus on the alert and screen reader reads it multiple time which is annoying to user.

Is there a place where I can proper solution of these kind of problem or is it problem with screen reader?

Comment: You can find some good examples here http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/alert/index.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<div clas="container">
  <div role="alert" aria-labelledby="abcd"tabindex=-1 class="validation-summary">
    <ul>
      <li> <h1 id="abcd"><a href=# >Please enter first name</a></h1></li>
      <li> <h1 id="abcd"><a href=# >Please enter lastname</a></h1></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```